# Hi. I have a question about lua, specifically creating local tables and returning them

Tags: memory, collections, lua, roblox, garbage

```
function createtable()
local table = {}
-- insert stuff into table like references to stuff or variables
return table
end


-- we'll use a different table
local globaltable = createtable()
```

My question is do we now have 2 tables?

What happens if I do `globaltable = nil`. Does the local table still exist and hold those references?
If I edit something in the local table such as removing everything in the local table after returning it will it influence the globaltable?

This is so confusing!!

I don't want memory to be building up.
For context I'm making a game on roblox and their code uses LUA which is interpreted by C or smth.
What I want to do is ensure that references are removed when they're no longer needed.

Comment: `a={}; b=a` creates one table and two references to it.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is do we now have 2 tables?

No. You have one table and one local variable called `globaltable` that references your one table. The local variable `localtable` will have gone out of scope after your function has returned.

> What happens if I do globaltable = nil. Does the local table still exist and hold those references?

As soon as the function returns, the local variable `localtable` goes out of scope. `globaltable` is then the only variable referencing ("holding") your table. After `globaltable = nil`, Lua will be able to **garbage-collect** your table, removing it whenever appropriate.

> If I edit something in the local table such as removing everything in the local table after returning it will it influence the globaltable?

Yes. Lua tables are reference objects: No matter the variables you use, you still have one table. You won't be able to modify the `localtable` variable after it has gone out of scope though; you'd have to keep it alive as upvalue of another function or the like.

> I don't want memory to be building up. What I want to do is ensure that references are removed when they're no longer needed.

Lua ensures this as it is **garbage-collected**: When an object such as a table is not referenced anymore (including references held by other tables / functions / userdata), Lua will eventually free the memory.

Memory leaks in Lua are only possible if you populate tables or other objects that hold references longer than they should (i.e. you forget to remove the references as soon as you don't need them).